# Play two sounds in one time

Tags: blackberry, media-player

I have 2 Player instnace. One need to play background sound, second to play other sound.

Background sound play in loop

```java
bgPlayer.setLoopCount(-1);
try { 
  bgPlayer.start();
} catch (MediaException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I  try to play background sound and then play other play another sound, the background sound is stopped (9860) and in some simulator or device (9800 torch) both sound are playing but sound quality is deteriorating.

How to play two sounds simultaneously?